# How to declare assumed sized device array in Cuda Fortran?

Tags: cuda, fortran

Here is the sample code in which I'm trying to process an array using Cuda Fortran.

```
    module mathOps
    contains
      attributes(global) subroutine saxpy(x, y, a)
        implicit none
        real :: x(:), y(:)
        real, value :: a
        integer :: i, n
        n = size(x)
        i = blockDim%x * (blockIdx%x - 1) + threadIdx%x
        if (i <= n) y(i) = y(i) + a*x(i)
      end subroutine saxpy 
    end module mathOps

    SUBROUTINE testSaxpy(x,y)
      use mathOps
      use cudafor
      implicit none

      real :: x(*), y(*), a
      real, device :: x_d(*), y_d(*) ! This line shows error and I want a statement that is something like this.
      type(dim3) :: grid, tBlock

      tBlock = dim3(256,1,1)
      grid = dim3(ceiling(real(N)/tBlock%x),1,1)


      x_d = x
      y_d = y
      call saxpy<<<grid, tBlock>>>(x_d, y_d, a)
      y = y_d
      write(*,*) 'Max error: ', maxval(abs(y-4.0))
    END SUBROUTINE testSaxpy


    PROGRAM TEST
        integer, parameter :: N = 40000
    real :: x(100), y(100), a
    x = 1.0; y = 2.0; a = 2.0
    testSaxpy(x,y)
    END TEST
```

Is there any way in which I can declare device array variable of assumed size or anything similar to that. I could declare fixed-sized arrays, but the problem is I dont have the file containing the main program. I am only provided with the subroutine file and I need to invoke cuda kernel from the subroutine. So, is there any way in which i can use assumed sized device arrays or anything like that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with CUDA fortran, but how about `real, device :: x_d(size(x)), y_d(size(y))`? Also, you should mention which error message you get.

Comment: You must show the error you see.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is

```
real, device :: x_d(size(x)), y_d(size(y))
```

This will allocate arrays `x_d` and `y_d` with the same size as `x` and `y` respectively. You can also declare the arrays as `allocatable` and then allocate them in the body,

```
real, device, allocatable :: x_d(:), y_d(:)
allocate(x_d(size(x)), y_d(size(y)))
```

But from my cursory reading about CUDA functions, it seems like it might be possible to make fortran do all of this transparently by telling it that you want `x` and `y` to be available on the device in the first place (not tested!):

```
subroutine testSaxpy(x,y)
  use mathOps
  use cudafor
  implicit none
  real, device :: x(:), y(:), a
  type(dim3) :: grid, tBlock

  tBlock = dim3(256,1,1)
  grid = dim3(ceiling(real(N)/tBlock%x),1,1)
  call saxpy<<<grid, tBlock>>>(x, y, a)
  write(*,*) 'Max error: ', maxval(abs(y-4.0))
end subroutine
```